# Idiomatic F# for "only once" post-initialization mutation?

Tags: f#, functional-programming

In the following, the way I define `Animator` is common in OOP systems, where it is considered fine to mutate `this` object's state:

```
type MyViewController() = 
    inherit UIViewController() 

    //Is there a better way than this?
    member val Animator = null with get, set 

    override this.ViewDidLoad() = 
        base.ViewDidLoad()

        //this.View is defined in base class and is only valid *now*
        this.Animator <- new UIDynamicAnimator(this.View)
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to define `Animator` that communicates: "`null`->object is ok, object -> object is forbidden"?

(Obviously, I could write a custom `set` function that checks and throws at runtime, but that seems more annoyingly "clever" than helpful.)

Comment: what about `Lazy<'a>`?

Comment: aside from this don't use `null` - use `Option<'a>` ;)

Comment: To be fair, in an OO code where the initialization is done in a way like this, I would probably just use `null`. Wrapping everything in options does not help much, because you'll always want to assume that the framework initialized things for you (so with option, you'd probably just write `Option.get`, which is not much better than using `null`). Building a more usable functional layer on top of this is certainly possible, but might be a lot of work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the library depends so heavily on inheritance, it is really hard to avoid the usual OO patterns, even when you're using F#. So to be fair, I would probably write exactly the same code you did and just live with the fact that this part of the code is not going to be that pretty (and use more functional approach in the parts of the application where you're not forced into OO style by the framework).

Also, in this case, I'd just live with the `null` - you can use `option`, but you're not getting any benefits, because you cannot do much if the value is `None` anyway.

Presumably, in your full source code, you are overriding other methods of the class and you are creating `Animator` so that it can be used in the other methods. One thing you could do is to extract the code from the class and write something like this:

```
type IInitializedView = 
    abstract OtherMethod : UIViewController -> unit

type MyViewController(viewInitialized:UIView -> IInitializedView) = 
    inherit UIViewController()     
    let mutable initializedView = None

    override this.ViewDidLoad() = 
        base.ViewDidLoad()
        initializedView := Some(viewInitialized this.View)

    override this.OtherMethod() = 
        viewInitialized |> Option.iter (fun vi ->
            vi.OtherMethod() )
```

The idea here is that `MyViewController` calls your function when it has view and your function then creates a new interface that handles the other method - but your interface is created only *after* everything is properly initialized!

```
let vc = MyViewController(fun view ->
  // Now we have valid 'view' so we construct animator!
  let animator = UIDynamicAnimator(view)
  { new IInitializedView with
      member x.OtherMethod() = 
        // no problem here, because we have animator... 
        animator.Whatever() })
```

But I don't know enough about Xamarin to say whether this would work OK in a full more complex system.

Answer (score 3):

I think what @Carsten gets at is that you shouldn't introduce null values unless you are absolutely forced to by interop with other CLI languages. Types declared in F# wouldn't allow them anyway, unless decorated with an `AllowNullLiteralAttribute`.

The value wrapped in the `Option<'a>` type would be a somewhat direct translation, but still has mutability. I'm assuming that you do not really need the property setter, replacing the automatic property with a let-bound value.

```
type MyViewController() = 
    inherit UIViewController() 

    let mutable animator = Option<UIDynamicAnimator>.None
    member x.Animator = animator.Value

    override this.ViewDidLoad() =
        base.ViewDidLoad()
        animator <- Some <| new UIDynamicAnimator(this.View)
```

On the other hand, wrapping in `Lazy<'a>` is a little bit more in the functional spirit.

```
type MyViewController() as this = 
    inherit UIViewController() 

    let animator = lazy(new UIDynamicAnimator(this.View))
    member x.Animator = animator.Value

    override this.ViewDidLoad() =
        base.ViewDidLoad()
        // Optional; only if you need the object creation right now
        animator.Force() |> ignore
```